# Error inserting into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, include

I have an error trying to insert into db using a function! 
I tried at first to pass `$connection` variable from my "included connect.php" but it got me an error can't pass an object or something like that. 
Now I repeated the connection part inside the function but still, i can't add a user!

Now the error is  not displayed, it just jumps to the else ... for example

```
 <?php
  function enterToDb($user, $pass, $email, $gender){
    // take those and insert into users

    $dbname = "mydb";
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", $dbname);
    //query
    $query= "insert into users";
    $query.=" (`username`, `password`, `email`)";
    $query.= " values ('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."','".$gender."')";
    if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)){
      ?>
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Congratulations! you're a member of E-Bridge community!
          </br>

          </div>

        <?php
    }else{
      ?>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Error signing you up! Please try again! 
      </div>
      <?php
    }



  }
```

As shown above is the function and it enters the function but jumps to the else directly

Here is where i referenced to the function

```
<?php
 echo"in sign up pages";
    $yes=0;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      // get all the info from the form
      $username= $_POST['username'];
      $password= $_POST['password'];
      $email= $_POST['email'];
      $gender=$_POST["radioGroup"];
      // check if the user already exists in the db
      $query= "select * from users where ";
      $query.= "username =\"".$username."\"";
      $query.= " or email=\"". $email."\"";
      //echo $query;
      $select= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($select)>=1){ // checking if rows exist
        // if so
        ?>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Credential already exists, please try another name or email.</div>
        <?php

        display();



      }else{
         //echo $username." ".$password." ".$email." ".$gender; 
        enterToDb($username, $password, $email, $gender);

      //display();
      }


      // if not there > error
      // else = exitst >> start session and direct to topics or profile ;)



    }else{


      display();

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Did you check the resultant SQL statement ? You'd better echo it out .

Comment: mistake in query, its not matching ... fields and its values

Comment: are you sure that the query is working fine... Once check your query...

Comment: You are adding `$gender` value but its not there in insert into

Comment: I modified that mistake, but I'm getting the same issue. Thank you all.

Comment: I echoed the statement and it was like
insert into users (`username`, `password`, `email`, 'gender') values ('test2','test','test2@gmail.com','M')

Comment: insert into users (username, password, email, gender) values ('test2','test','test2@gmail.com','M')

Answer (score 1):

```
$query.=" (`username`, `password`, `email`)";
$query.= " values ('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."','".$gender."')";
```

3 field names, 4 values being inserted. I think you'll find you need to add gender into your fields.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but getting the same issue :\